# Accessing a TableView within a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a ViewController that has a `UITableView` within it. When I'm watching tutorials people are using things like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _Title.count;
}
```

How am I able to generate the stubs without firstly creating the class with them in. When I made the class I selected it as a `UIViewController`. I've been playing around trying to auto generate the stubs but all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the `UITableViewDataSource` (and most likely the `UITableViewDelegate`) to your UIViewController declaration. Example:

```
// MyViewController.h

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
// ...
@end
```

After that your implementation file MyViewcontroller.m should help you with the code completion.

One note: don't forget to set yourself as dataSource:
`_tableview.dataSource = self;`

Answer (score 1):

If you added the tableview by code, you need to create a property (weak) in order to have a reference to your table view after adding it to your view controller's subview. If you add it by using interface builder, you need to create a iboutlet property that will allow you to "bind" your table view property with the xib/storyboard file representing your view controller. Alternatively, you can use UITableViewController as the parent class of your view controller. This class already has a property to access the table view in your view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Tell your controller that you need to conform to the table view protocols and they will start to auto-complete when you try to type them in. You can check the docs of a protocol to find the available methods. Checking the `UITableView` docs would tell you about the relevant data source and delegate:

> The data source must adopt the UITableViewDataSource protocol and the delegate must adopt the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

In your header file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

You could make your class inherit from `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController`. This will give you a `tableView` so you don't need to make one.

Or...

Your `UIViewController` could implement the protocols `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`. Then set the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties of your table view to `self` (your view controller containing the table).

Answer (score 1):

-First of all you may need to add datasource and delegate of UITableViewController in your UIViewController header file

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

and then implement the required and optional methods to populate the data in your _tableView.

Sample Code for TableView demonstration by Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318